# why Kafka failing on ambari installation?

Tags: apache-kafka, ambari, hortonworks-dataflow

I am trying to do an install of Horton works data flow 3.3 using ambari. Before installation of services it fails on Kafka. I have tried deleting and recreating the repo with no success. The error says it can't find the baseurl. I am using the baseurl below. Has anyone ran into this issue? 
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDF/centos7/3.x/updates/3.3.0.0

> Error getting repository data for HDF-3.3, repository not found
>
> 2019-04-05 10:47:03,346 - The 'kafka-broker' component did not
>   advertise a version. This may indicate a problem with the component
>   packaging. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDF/3.3/services/KAFKA/package/scripts/kafka_broker.py",
>   line 145, in 
>       KafkaBroker().execute()   File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py",
>   line 351, in execute
>       method(env)   File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDF/3.3/services/KAFKA/package/scripts/kafka_broker.py",
>   line 40, in install
>       self.install_packages(env)   File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py",
>   line 836, in install_packages
>       name = self.format_package_name(package['name'])   File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py",
>   line 558, in format_package_name
>       return self.get_package_from_available(name)   File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py",
>   line 525, in get_package_from_available
>       raise Fail("No package found for {0}(expected name: {1})".format(name, name_with_version))
>   resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: No package found for
>   kafka_${stack_version}(expected name: kafka_3_3)
>
> 019-04-05 10:46:55,948 - Stack Feature Version Info: Cluster
>   Stack=3.3, Command Stack=None, Command Version=None -> 3.3 2019-04-05
>   10:46:55,951 - Group['hadoop'] {} 2019-04-05 10:46:55,952 -
>   Group['nifi'] {} 2019-04-05 10:46:55,952 - User['logsearch'] {'gid':
>   'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid':
>   None} 2019-04-05 10:46:55,965 - User['infra-solr'] {'gid': 'hadoop',
>   'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:55,980 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop',
>   'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,006 - User['ams'] {'gid': 'hadoop',
>   'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,022 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop',
>   'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,033 - User['kafka'] {'gid': 'hadoop',
>   'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['hadoop'], 'uid': None}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,057 - User['nifi'] {'gid': 'hadoop',
>   'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': ['nifi'], 'uid': None}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,068 -
>   File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content':
>   StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555} 2019-04-05
>   10:46:56,070 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh
>   ambari-qa
>   /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa
>   0'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,074 - Skipping
>   Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa
>   /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa
>   0'] due to not_if 2019-04-05 10:46:56,085 - Repository for
>   HDF/3.3/HDF-3.3 is not managed by Ambari 2019-04-05 10:46:56,085 -
>   Repository for HDF/3.3/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22 is not managed by Ambari
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,085 - Repository[None] {'action': ['create']}
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,087 - Package['unzip']
>   {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5} 2019-04-05
>   10:46:56,237 - Skipping installation of existing package unzip
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,237 - Package['curl']
>   {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5} 2019-04-05
>   10:46:56,257 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,257 - Package['hdf-select']
>   {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5} 2019-04-05
>   10:46:56,276 - Skipping installation of existing package hdf-select
>   2019-04-05 10:46:56,321 - call[('ambari-python-wrap',
>   u'/usr/bin/hdf-select', 'versions')] {} 2019-04-05 10:46:56,339 - call
>   returned (1, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   "/usr/bin/hdf-select", line 406, in \n    printVersions()\n 
>   File "/usr/bin/hdf-select", line 251, in printVersions\n    for f in
>   os.listdir(root):\nOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   \'/usr/hdf\'') 2019-04-05 10:46:56,571 - Command repositories:
>   HDF-3.3, HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22 2019-04-05 10:46:56,571 - Applicable
>   repositories: HDF-3.3, HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22 2019-04-05 10:46:56,572 -
>   Looking for matching packages in the following repositories: HDF-3.3,
>   HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22 2019-04-05 10:46:56,795 - Command execution error:
>   command = "/usr/bin/yum list available --showduplicates
>   --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=HDF-3.3", exit code = 1, stderr =
>
> Error getting repository data for HDF-3.3, repository not found
>
> 2019-04-05 10:47:03,326 - call[('ambari-python-wrap',
>   u'/usr/bin/hdf-select', 'versions')] {} 2019-04-05 10:47:03,346 - call
>   returned (1, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   "/usr/bin/hdf-select", line 406, in \n    printVersions()\n 
>   File "/usr/bin/hdf-select", line 251, in printVersions\n    for f in
>   os.listdir(root):\nOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   \'/usr/hdf\'') 2019-04-05 10:47:03,346 - The 'kafka-broker' component
>   did not advertise a version. This may indicate a problem with the
>   component packaging.

Command failed after 1 tries

Comment: `No such file or directory: \'/usr/hdf\'`, so something else failed, not just kafka installation

Comment: I am getting this same problem. I'm installing other packages through Ambari. For me it is failing at installing the DRPC server. I think what it's failing at is less important than the fact the `/usr/hdf` directory is not created. I have `/usr/hdp` on my node, but not `/usr/hdf`.